# How do you make a child constructor private when the parent is public?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, constructor

Why is it not possible to hide the constructor in a child class?

I am getting the following Exception:

> Fatal error: Access level to CIS\Logger\WPLogger::__construct() must
>   be public (as in class Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger) in
>   /builds/r2o/website/wp-content/mu-plugins/toolsets/lib/cis-logger/src/WPLogger.php
>   on line 12

Code of superclass (from external library):

```
    public function __construct($logDirectory, $logLevelThreshold = LogLevel::DEBUG, array $options = array()) { // ... 
    }
```

Code of WPLogger.php (subclass):

```
private function __construct(string $logDirectory, string $logLevelThreshold = LogLevel::DEBUG, array $options = array()) {
    parent::__construct($logDirectory, $logLevelThreshold, $options);
         // ... some actions
    }
}

public static function getInstance(string $logFileRelative = self::DEFAULT_LOG_NAME, string $logLevelThreshold = LogLevel::DEBUG, array $options = array()) {
       // ...
}
```

I do not want this special subclass to be instantiated with `new`. I want it to be created statically with `getInstance()` instead for some reasons. How can I achieve this?

Comment: does the superclass implement an interface?

Comment: Nope: `extends AbstractLogger` but no interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand methods visibility with the usage of inheritance. The following example is correct

```
class A
{
   private function __construct()
   {}
}

class B extends A
{

   public function __construct()
   {}
}
```

But you aren't able to restrict methods visibility in children's classes. The following example is incorrect

```
class A
{
   public function __construct()
   {}
}

class B extends A
{
   private function __construct()
   {}
}
```

In your case, you try to hide constructor because you want to make the singleton. Singleton is bad practice in many cases. You should use
other patterns for object builing: [Static Factory](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Creational/StaticFactory/README.html), [Service Locator](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/More/ServiceLocator/README.html), [Dependency Injection Container](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html)

For example, you can archive the necessary result with the simple modification of static factory:

```
class LoggerFactory
{
    private static $instance = null;

    public static function build()
    {
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) { 
            static::$instance = // making of the logger
        }
        return static:$instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Every answer offers a good way to solve it. For my case I decided your factory to be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any way to force a child class to accept a lower level of [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) than the parent function you're overwriting.

What you probably want here is a wrapper class that emulates the parent but does not `extend` it

```
class Singleton {
    /** @var \Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger */
    protected $logger;
    /** @var Singleton */
    protected $instance;

    private function __construct($someargs) {
         $this->logger = new \Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger($someargs);
    }

    public static function getInstance($someargs) {
         if($this->instance instanceof Singleton) return $this->instance;
         $this->instance = new self($someargs);
         return $this->instance;
    }

    /** Magic method to pass along calls to the other class */
    function __call($method, $args) {
         call_user_func_array(array($this->logger, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also a good idea for my current case I decided to stay with the suggested factory solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a subclass method ( in this case is a constructor, but same principle applies ) more restrictive than the parent class. Because the client code that will use that *type* expect to have the same contract/interface of the super class. Otherwise you cannot replace an instance of the super class with an instance of your class transparently, and viceversa.

But, your super class depends on `AbstractLogger` which implements from `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`. And since I'm *sure* that everybody follow the Dependency Inversion Principle, you should be able to say that it's fine for `WPLogger` to implements directly from `LoggerInterface`. So:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

final class WPLogger implements LoggerInterface
{
    private $wrapperLogger;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance(string $logFileRelative = self::DEFAULT_LOG_NAME, string $logLevelThreshold = LogLevel::DEBUG, array $options = array()) {
       // @TODO, implement here your singleton if you want

       $self = new self();
       $self->wrapperLogger = new \Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger(...);
       return $self;
    }

    // implement the rest of the interface, delegating to wrapperLogger
}
```

Comment: A nice solution with interfaces just for my current case I decided to solve it with the Factory pattern.